# Extension of rational maps over common compactification

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $U$ be a smooth variety of dimension at most $2$ over a field $k$. Suppose $f, g: U \to X$ is a morphism of $k$-schemes where  $X$ is a smooth proper $k$-scheme. Then there is a smooth proper compactification $\bar{U}$ of $U$ such that both $f$ and $g$ can be extended to a morphism from $\bar{U}$ to X. 
I know this is true for curve. I can't find any proof in case of surface. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is your third post on this subject in the last 24 hours. Is there some bigger question going on in the background?

Comment: This is the question I am seeking for..I am looking for given $n$ many morphisms $f_1, f_2, ..., f_n:U \to X$ there is a common compactification of $U$ such that all extends to.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the morphism $f \times g \colon U \to X \times X$, then find a compactification $\bar{U}$ and an extension $\bar{U} \to X \times X$ of $f \times g$, and then consider the compositions $\bar{U} \to X \times X \to X$, where the last arrow is a projection onto a factor.

Needless to say, the same works for any number of morphisms.